# Why android studio does not sign my apps?

Tags: android, key, sign

I read some of post in Stackoverflow, but I see alot of people says to add sign key to gradle, I don't want that, coz I read is risky, so how I signet apk or aab was from menu >

**Build** >> **Generate signed bundle/apk** >> **Android app bundle**

I select key pass and everything and when I click **ok** >>

**I check build variant release** >> and click **finish**
 and I get aab file as result but is not signed, I try the same with apk and ways and app is not signed.
This happens after update of Android Studio. Any help will be appreciated.

I'm trying to sign app.aab from apk-signer-1.8.5 but when I upload it says:

**The Android App Bundle was not signed.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resoloved by Uninstalling Android Studio complete, with all user data.
Just be sure to backup your keystore and projects before uninstalling.